# Using infer from the proof package?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I am using the `\infer` command from the `proof` package. Few things that I am trying to do unsuccessfully:

1. How can I have some space between the elements of the proof? such as space between x and y with    `\infer{x y}{z}`. I can use `\,`, but there should be a better way to do it, I think.
2. `\begin{center}` has no effect on any of the inference rules, and I still want to be able to center them.
3. How would I set up space between the inference rules without using `vspace`? Right now, they appear very crowded, one right under the other.

Comment: a tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as Martin did in his edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. I guess you have to do the spacing manually, just like with any occurrence of `x y` within the text.
2. You can center rules by `\[ ... \]` and (deprecated) `$$...$$`.
3. You could adjust the length `\inferLineSkip`.

Here's a minimal example showing the tips above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\setlength{\inferLineSkip}{4pt}
\begin{document}
\infer{B}{A & (A \rightarrow B)}
\[\infer{xy}{z}\]
\infer{C}{D & (D \leftarrow B)}
\end{document}
```

[image]