# How to align the content inside \left \right?

Tags: alignment

Here is my code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{proof}
\newcommand{\subtyp}[2]{#1<:#2}

\begin{document}

$$
\left\llbracket \infer{\subtyp{S}{T}}{C_1:: \subtyp{S}{U} & C_2:: \subtyp{U}{T}} \right\rrbracket
$$

\end{document}
```

It shows

[image]

The content insided the delimeter seems top-aligning, I want it to be like as follow
[image]

You can see there are some blank at bottom of my picture, I want the content inside the delimeter to be center. How should I do it? Here is one online latex view https://www.overleaf.com/read/ypwgkhjkdgqm

If I replace `\infer` to `\frac`, it can be easily seen the difference.
[image]

Comment: Can you please show a complete example? It is very unclear what your "infer" is doing.

Comment: @mickep Corrected it

Comment: @maplgebra, your document example cannot be compiled. It contain undefined control sequences. Please, make it compilable!

Comment: OK, next thing is the proof package. It does not seem to be [this one](https://ctan.org/pkg/proof?lang=en). Difficult to help in any way. You could probably manually add space with `\,` or so.

Comment: @Zarko Fixed, please try it again.

Comment: @mickep the proof package was mentioned at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/using-infer-from-the-proof-package

Comment: Never ever use `$$` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{proof}

\newcommand{\subtyp}[2]{#1<:#2}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\llbracket
  \begin{gathered}
  \infer{\subtyp{S}{T}}{C_1:: \subtyp{S}{U} & C_2:: \subtyp{U}{T}}
  \end{gathered}
\right\rrbracket
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe adding `\,` at either side is better:

```
\[
\left\llbracket\,
  \begin{gathered}
  \infer{\subtyp{S}{T}}{C_1:: \subtyp{S}{U} & C_2:: \subtyp{U}{T}}
  \end{gathered}
\,\right\rrbracket
\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what you like to achieve with your math expression. A simple way, which reproduce your second image is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\newcommand{\subtyp}[2]{#1<:#2}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\llbracket 
\raisebox{-1.5ex}{
\infer[(S-\textsc{Trans})]{\subtyp{S}{T}}{C_1:: \subtyp{S}{U} 
                            & 
                           C_2:: \subtyp{U}{T}}} 
\right\rrbracket
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

If you for some reason persist to use `proof` packae anfd it syntax, than you may like to use `raisebox` command for vertical align your proof between `\llbracket` and `\llbracket`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{proof}
\newcommand{\subtyp}[2]{#1<:#2}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\llbracket 
\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\infer[(S-\textsc{Trans})]{\subtyp{S}{T}}{C_1:: \subtyp{S}{U} 
                        & C_2:: 
                         \subtyp{U}{T}}} \right\rrbracket
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems `\frac` works well, but `\infer` not.

Comment: Can u check my updated question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `proof` package nor with it syntax. In your simple case, I also don't see any benefit to use it.  If you persist to use `\infer` command, than search this site or package documentation, if somewhere is solved your problem or wait on someone, who know solution. BTW, it seems that `proof` expression is not indent to be used inside math environments. Also baseline of its expression is at its bottom what seems to cause your problem.

Comment: @maplgebra, see addendum to answer ...

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @maplgebra, this site has policy that you express your thankfulness by up-voting answer and the best of them even accept (by clicking on up-triangle and check mark at top left side of answer) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can place the expression inside an `\hbox`, inside `\vcenter`:

[image]

Note that you must re-enter math mode.

```
\[
\left\llbracket \vcenter{\hbox{$\infer{\subtyp{S}{T}}{C_1:: \subtyp{S}{U} & C_2:: \subtyp{U}{T}}$}} \right\rrbracket
\]
```

Comment: Too complicated. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Yeah, I guess the `\hbox` is unnecessary here.

Comment: The `\hbox` is definitely necessary here. Otherwise, `$...$` inside the `\vcenter` will start a paragraph (which has a width of the text block)—probably not desired.

Comment: @RuixiZhang: `\hbox` is unnecessary here if you delete the `$`s.